# iframe loading with no height in IE 10

Tags: iframe, panel, yui, internet-explorer-10

Using YUI, I have created help pages that load into a panel through use of an iframe. The panel is hidden to begin with and shown with the simple click of a help button.

In Chrome, FF, and Safari, the iframe loads to the proper size and is resizeable. In IE 10 the iframe loads with no height value (0px) and only becomes visible once resized for the first time. This shows all the content loaded into the iframe. The iframe loads properly with the resize functions disabled on the panel.

Do you have any advice? Is this a IE problem or code problem?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone that finds this, I have solved the problem by making the button that shows the panel do a resize by force. I create the panel as 500x499 and when the button is clicked, the panel resizes to 500x500 and shows the hidden panel. This is not the most elegant solution, it has worked for me.